# Python tuple for Counter

Tags: python, tuples, counter

```
str_tuple = "abcd",
a = Counter()  
a.update(str_tuple)
```

but `a[('abcd',)] == 0` because the `Counter` counted the `'abcd'` string, not the tuple. I need to count the tuple.

Answer (score 4):

`Counter.update()` takes a *sequence* of things to count. If you need to count a tuple, put that value into a sequence before passing it to the `Counter.update()` method:

```
a.update([str_tuple])
```

or use:

```
a[str_tuple] += 1
```

to increment the count for that one tuple by one.

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> str_tuple = "abcd",
>>> a = Counter()  
>>> a.update([str_tuple])
>>> a
Counter({('abcd',): 1})
>>> a = Counter()  
>>> a[str_tuple] += 1
>>> a
Counter({('abcd',): 1})
```